# How do I add a "stringField component" under a DataView (that is a custom connection) in Rave?

Tags: delphi

So, I have inhertited this Delphi application that does reporting with Rave (Version 6.5) and I need to
add a field to one of these reports.

Now, I have gotten completely stuck. There's this *DataView* that (I suppose) funnels the data from the application to the report. This DataView is a *custom data dataview* and contains the fields that are displayed on the report (as can be seen by opening the TreeView on the left side). I *think* I should add a new field under this DataView in order be able to write the new data unto the report. But I have no idea how that could be done.

I can "select" an already existing "text field" (and a green arrowish thingy is displayed next to it) and then use the right mouse button for *copy* and *paste* but nothing particular happens.

So any pointers to this are *very* appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem.

The project must be running while the report is created. Here's the link that helped me find the solution. 
www.delphigroups.info/2/8/358915.html

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this but just found a way that works for me in the Rave Designer without starting over.

1. Add a new dummy DataView: File | New Data Object | Direct Data View | (selected any data collection) | Finish
2. Your new DataView will be created with a StringField component below it. Holding the CTRL key, drag the new StringField component to your existing DataView (drop it on the pink "view" cylinder icon.(
3. Rename the moved StringField and change its properties to whatever you want to match your Delphi code.
4. Delete the new DataView you created.